# Repeat JQuery .each() function infinite number of times

Tags: jquery

How would one make this each function keep on performing forever.

```
$('.featuedbanner img').each(function(){
    $(this).delay(featlay).animate({opacity: 1,  leaveTransforms:true}, {duration:2000, queue:true});
    featlay += 6000;
    $(this).delay(featlay).animate({opacity: 0,  leaveTransforms:true}, {duration:2000, queue:true});
});
```

That is to make this an infinite loop

Comment: I don't think you're making it very clear what you want to do...

Comment: @sth That is to make this an infinite loop

Comment: Infinite loop isn't the correct term here.. what you really looking for is code that infinitely calls itself again.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to do some thing like this to achieve the following

[Jsfiddle Example1](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/JJfKM/20/)

Also

[Jsfiddle Example2](http://jsfiddle.net/tjAa6/)

Comment: It's always better to post the actual code in your SO answer, in case jsFiddle is down or vanishes completely.

Comment: Ya I agree to that...but my answer is just a reference as there is not html code to help it out

Comment: I, speaking only for myself, will not upvote an answer if I can't see the solution in the answer itself.

Comment: @Wazzzy: What about a simple explanation? "You need to use a timeout rather than a loop. See here for an explanation"...

Comment: Both examples iterate through values of an array. I would not upvote this answer for the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var loop = function(){
    var featlay = 0;
    $('.featuedbanner img').each(function(){
            $(this).delay(featlay).animate({opacity: 1,  leaveTransforms:true}, {duration:2000, queue:true});
            featlay += 6000;
            $(this).delay(featlay).animate({opacity: 0,  leaveTransforms:true}, {duration:2000, queue:true});
        });

    setTimeout(loop, 0);
};

loop();
```

Comment: GOOD, but seams to take 3 times the length of time to trigger and and loop round again. This is because there are currently three images. So it is multiplying the quantity by the feat lay variable for some reason

Comment: You will have to put `featlay` inside the loop and reset it at the beginning of each. Or just pass constants to `delay` method. Right now you are doing `+=`

Comment: I tried this to no avail. If I set constants then all images trigger fading at the same time

Comment: already tried that. Causing very strange backwards issues. Here is a FIDDLE ... http://jsfiddle.net/6JmDV/1/